# Software to grab HD still image from USB microscope

Tags: usb, webcam

I have bought a 20 USD handheld USB-microscope.

Video works in 640x480 with `webcamoid`, but the microscope is supposed to support still images at 1920x1080.

My guess is that I simply run the wrong software (and that `webcamoid`'s still image is just taking a frame from the video stream - thus only gives 640x480).

How can I take a still image in the high resolution?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 032: ID 05e3:f12a Genesys Logic, Inc. USB2.0 Digital Camera

$ v4l-info /dev/video2

### v4l2 device info [/dev/video2] ###
general info
    VIDIOC_QUERYCAP
        driver                  : "uvcvideo"
        card                    : "USB2.0 Digital Camera: USB2.0 D"
        bus_info                : "usb-0000:00:14.0-1"
        version                 : 5.4.44
        capabilities            : 0x84a00001 [VIDEO_CAPTURE,?,?,STREAMING,(null)]

standards

inputs
    VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT(0)
        index                   : 0
        name                    : "Camera 1"
        type                    : CAMERA
        audioset                : 0
        tuner                   : 0
        std                     : 0x0 []
        status                  : 0x0 []

video capture
    VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT(0,VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        index                   : 0
        type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
        flags                   : 0
        description             : "YUYV 4:2:2"
        pixelformat             : 0x56595559 [YUYV]
    VIDIOC_G_FMT(VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        type                    : VIDEO_CAPTURE
        fmt.pix.width           : 640
        fmt.pix.height          : 480
        fmt.pix.pixelformat     : 0x56595559 [YUYV]
        fmt.pix.field           : NONE
        fmt.pix.bytesperline    : 1280
        fmt.pix.sizeimage       : 614400
        fmt.pix.colorspace      : SRGB
        fmt.pix.priv            : 4276996862

controls
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+0)
        id                      : 9963776
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Brightness"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 127
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 0
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+1)
        id                      : 9963777
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Contrast"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 80
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 54
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+2)
        id                      : 9963778
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Saturation"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 176
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 130
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+3)
        id                      : 9963779
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Hue"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 8
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 0
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+12)
        id                      : 9963788
        type                    : BOOLEAN
        name                    : "White Balance Temperature, Auto"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 1
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 1
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+16)
        id                      : 9963792
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Gamma"
        minimum                 : 1
        maximum                 : 5
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 3
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+19)
        id                      : 9963795
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Gain"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 64
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 32
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+24)
        id                      : 9963800
        type                    : MENU
        name                    : "Power Line Frequency"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 2
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 1
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+26)
        id                      : 9963802
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "White Balance Temperature"
        minimum                 : 2800
        maximum                 : 6500
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 5900
        flags                   : INACTIVE
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+27)
        id                      : 9963803
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Sharpness"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 5
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 1
        flags                   : unknown
    VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL(BASE+28)
        id                      : 9963804
        type                    : INTEGER
        name                    : "Backlight Compensation"
        minimum                 : 0
        maximum                 : 2
        step                    : 1
        default_value           : 1
        flags                   : unknown
```